# $convert is not allowed or the syntax is incorrect in MongoDB playground

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm new to the MongoDB, and attempting to convert an `age` field from string to int.
However, using the `$convert` function, I get an error stating that `$convert is not allowed or the syntax is incorrect`.

My code is as below:

```
db['1947'].aggregate(
    [
        {
          $convert: {
            input: "$age",
            to: "int",
            onError: "An error occurred",
            onNull: "Input was null or empty"
          }
        }
    ]
)
```

The following code is working and providing me with the expected output:

```
db['1947'].aggregate(
    [
      {
        $project:
          {
            _id: 0,
            result:
            {
              $convert: {
                input: "$age",
                to: "int",
                onError: "An error occurred",
                onNull: "Input was null or empty"
              }
            }
          }
      }
    ]
)
```

Does this mean that I cannot change the dataset from the playground? If so, how would I go about converting the `age` field?

Comment: The difference in 2 behaviours is expected, `$convert` is not one of the [top level aggregation operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/). You are expected to use `$convert` in a `$set`, `$project`, `$addFields`...

Comment: @user115592, I've converted your mongo query to text in a suggested edit. Remember to paste your code as text in the future!

Comment: @Holo Please see [Should we edit a question to transcribe code from an image to text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415040/16217248)

Comment: In the first query, the `$convert` is used as an aggregation _stage_. Hence, the error. In the second query `$convert` is used as an aggregation _operator_, correctly so.  Note that, you can use operators within a stage only. Both, have different functionality.